# System.Net.Mail replacing linefeeds in AlternateView content with spaces

Tags: c#, .net, email, encoding, icalendar

I'm using System.Net.Mail to send out an ics meeting/calendar invitation.  The line terminators (0D 0A) in the ics are being replaced with spaces (20 20) in the email that is received.  I've googled solutions and tried a few variations of the code below but none of them seem to fix this behavior.  Any ideas?

```
System.Net.Mail.MailMessage m = new System.Net.Mail.MailMessage();
System.Net.Mime.ContentType ct = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");

ct.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
ct.Parameters.Add("name", "meeting.ics");

AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString("<<data>>",ct);
avCal.TransferEncoding = System.Net.Mime.TransferEncoding.SevenBit;
m.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);
```

Answer (score 2):

use

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(body, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```

Answer (score 1):

Never mind. My bad...  Further debugging revealed that the problem had nothing to do with the encoding or mail portion. Actually looks like the linefeeds are being garbled somewhere between the SQL database and the app. Thanks to everyone who posted advice!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the overload for `AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString` that accepts an Encoding and MediaType? I use:

```
AlternateView htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(
            htmlBody, Encoding.UTF8, MediaTypeNames.Text.Html);
```

and it seems to work ok for me.

Comment: I don't see an overload for CreateAlternateViewFromString accepts a MediaTypeName as the 3rd parameter; it's just a string in .NET 3.5 and 4.0.  Also, wouldn't this result in content that is just text/html?  Not text/calendar?

Comment: That's odd. I have 3 overloads on .NET 4: string, string/Encoding/string and string/ContentType. Regardless, you're right - that will give text/html, not text/calendar.